# Vb.Net How Can I Send Video To Named Pipe?

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, named-pipes

I want to create name pipe and send all videos on my listbox to that named pipe. I can create a named pipe like this :

`Dim p_to_ffmpeg As NamedPipeServerStream
    p_to_ffmpeg = New NamedPipeServerStream("to_ffmpeg", PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.[Byte])`

But i have no idea how can i send video to a named pipe. I couldn't find any useful information. I want to use that named pipe on ffmpeg as a input for streaming. Thanks for every help!

Comment: If it's a vb.net question, why did you include the C# tag?

Comment: I could convert c# code to vb.net they are very similar. I apologize if I did something wrong.

Comment: Helpful tip - The reason that you shouldn't use incorrect tags is that some users who only understand c#, look for questions with the c# tag and don't want to see questions that are not directly related to c#. It will be very helpful to read [ask], but I understand that if English is not your first language, and it might be difficult. Good luck and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try to be much more careful. Thanks again for your kind message! :)